# The difference in usage between "also" and "as well"

Tags: word-usage, difference, usage

What's the difference between "also" and "as well"? Is the difference just in that fact that as well is often used in the end of a sentense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a pencil. Also I have a rubber.
>
> I have a pencil. I have a rubber as well.

My best guess is it's a matter of personal taste.
To my ears "as well" gives a sense of comparison and equality. "Also" gives me a sanse of addition and overloading.